# color doesn't change on Custom Text View class

Tags: java, android

changing text color attribute doesn't work with creaing custom TextView class on runtime, but the color change on design mode on IDE(android studio)

here is my layout code to add the CustomTextView with textColor attribute

```
<mypackage.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawablePadding="5dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="mytext"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
```

and my CustomTextView class and the way I implemented it

```
    public class CustomTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.e("test=","11111");
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.e("test=","2222");
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Log.e("test=","33333");
        init();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private void init() {
        Typeface font_type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Action_Man_Bold.ttf");
        setTypeface(font_type);
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


    }
}
```

in addition changing color programmatically doesn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is about some attributes doesn't work while some Visibility enhancements option are enabled, in my case disabling High contrast fonts solve the issue and the textColor attribute worked again.